# SQL Server Query performance view used in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, where-clause

I have a problem with a query in sql server.

I used a view in where clause like

```
SELECT ... 
FROM T1
WHERE 
(@param = 1 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VIEW...)) // in this case => use view
OR
(@param = 2 AND T1.Id = ...) // in this case => no view
```

I saw in execution plan that view is always build. But I don't want that.

Any idea?

Comment: If your refer to view in query this view is always  buil .. (dinamically generate)   a query can't be executed  partially ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your view to build in case where you don't need it then use dynamic SQL and conditionally enable and disable the view part when it's needed or not. Something like that:

```
declare @useView nvarchar(max) = '--'

if (@param = 1)
set @useView = ''

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT ... 
 FROM T1
 WHERE 1=1 '
 + @useView ' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VIEW...)) -- in this case => use view '
+'
 AND
 (@p_param = 2 AND T1.Id = ...) -- in this case => no view '

print @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@p_param INT',@p_param = @param
```

You need to make sure the whole SELECT referencing the VIEW fits 1 line to be covered by -- comment, otherwise use 2 comment variables for `/*` and `*/`.

Comment: it's exactly what i want. Just build view when its needed

Comment: I'll try... it's a query in a Reporting Services Report then i hope dynamic SQL works with SSRS.

Comment: @L.Toto try it out and let me know. But first, create a working query in SSMS and make sure it runs without errors when you run it manually.

Comment: @L.Toto just curious if you've managed to attach this dynamic SQL to your SSRS report?

Comment: I created a stored procedure called in my SSRS report.

Comment: @L.Toto, Glad that it worked. thanks for the accept and vote up!

Answer (score 0):

Move the parameter value check into the sub-query and the query optimizer should then be able to build a better plan:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM T1
WHERE 
(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM VIEW ... WHERE ... @param = 1)) // in this case => use view
OR
(@param = 2 AND T1.Id = ...) // in this case => no view
```